# extract the green vector from one image

Tags: python

I want to extract the green vector from one image. Image has red and green point and making grid

```
def each_green_vector(im):
     pixels = im.load_image(im)
     utils.apply_to_each_pixel(pixels, lambda x: 0.0 if x >10  else 1.0)

     msize = m_mesh.rows*m_mesh.cols;
     (x, y) = imsize
     vec = []
     for i in range(1,x -1):
        for j in range (1, y -1):
            grid = grid_at(pixels, i, j)
            if grid != "none":
                if grid ==1:
                    vec.append((i,j));
                    gx = list[i].x / m_mesh.gWidth;
                    gy = list[i].y / m_mesh.gHeight;
                    grid = gx + gy *m_mesh.cols; 
                    vec[grid] == 1;
     return vec
```

Comment: One possible solution could be to use OpenCV, a conversion in HSV, and then a color mask for green.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way I can think of is using the `misc` library of scipy. This [link](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/) can give you more detail, but the basic idea is this

```
from scipy import misc
arr = misc.imread(im) # 640x480x3 array
arr[20, 30] # all 3 vectors of a pixel
arr[20, 30, 1] # only green value for a pixel
```